# HttpWebRequest - Get a page from url and specific destination IP

Tags: asp.net, .net, httpwebrequest

I have this code to download a page from a remote url.

```
Dim request As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url)
Dim response As HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()
```

HttpWebRequests resolves the DNS for url and gets the IP.
What I need is to override that and connect to a different IP (using the same url)

That's because we are doing some lab testing and we want to get the page from each of our machine (each one with different private IP) behind the loadbalancer.

I tried to mess around with IPEndPoint but I was able to get it not to set it.

Found several questions about how to change originating IP, but I want to change the destination IP.

Any help?
Thanks

Comment: I think it would be simplest just to override the DNS itself on the testing machine...

Comment: thanks, but we want to make this by code for several reasons. One is because the code will request a page from several different IPs behind our load balancer (same URL) at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to modify your hosts file on your machine to resolve the DNS as you need.

In the host file, you can hard code the IP for each DNS name. The DNS client would look up in this file before getting to the DNS server.

I hope it answers your question.

Comment: Thanks, but as I said in a comment above, thanks, we want to make this by code for several reasons. One is because the code will request a page from several different IPs behind our load balancer (same URL) at the same time. So, changing the host file is not an option. Thanks